# How to write after a score with Lilypond

Tags: lilypond, engraving

So I want to write not just at the end of a score, but *after* it, like the dal segno on this snippet :

[image]

I find it really neat, but don't find how to do it. It is not a text script, spanner or mark. It is not an object. So I'm a loss at how to do it.

For now, I just add `_"D.S. al Fine" \bar "S-S"` at the end of my score, so the dal segno is below the score.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here I am overriding the barline stencil:

```
fancyMarkup = \markup \with-dimensions #'(0 . 0) #'(0 . 0) {
  \raise #-2.5 \center-column { "D.     S." "al" "Fin" }
}

\new StaffGroup <<
  \new Staff { b1 b b b b
               \once \override Staff.BarLine.stencil =
               #(lambda (grob)
                  (ly:stencil-combine-at-edge
                   (ly:bar-line::print grob)
                   X RIGHT
                   (grob-interpret-markup grob fancyMarkup)
                   0))
               \bar "S-S"
               }
  \new Staff { b1 b b b b }
>>
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

To be honest, I don't know an elegant way to do this and I would be very happy to see one. However, in the meantime, you can engrave it with use of a hack like this: [lilybin](http://lilybin.com/lacq8r/1).

What I did there is essentially this: I attach a markup to the last note in the right hand like so:

```
b-\tweak extra-offset #'(6 . 1.5) _\markup{\with-dimensions #'(0 . 0) #'(0 . 0) \center-column{ "D. S." "al" "Fin" }} \bar "S-S"
```

The main idea is to take what you want to typeset, which is `\center-column{"D. S." "al" "Fin"}`, make it take up no space using `\with-dimensions #'(0 . 0) #'(0 . 0) ...` and put the markup to the right place (found by trial and error) using `-\tweak extra-offset #'(X . Y)`. It's very ugly, but sadly I don't know of anything better and it at least gets the job done.